# wso2 api manager PUT method does not work in api store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Wso2 API Manager 1.10.0. PUT method does not work in API store.
GET, POST, DELETE methods work, but PUT dose not work.

Error,

```
Curl

curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer c6c90338514e561c8a02a7b6a1c96553" -d "{\"payment\":\"PAID\"}" "https://10.138.31.22:8243/Starbucks_API/1/order_1"

Request URL

https://10.138.31.22:8243/Starbucks_API/1/order_1

Response Body

<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
  <ams:code>900906</ams:code>
  <ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given request</ams:message>
  <ams:description>Access failure for API: /Starbucks_API/1, version: 1. Check the API documentation and add a proper REST resource path to the invocation URL</ams:description>
</ams:fault>

Response Code
403

Response Headers
{
  "content-type": "application/xml; charset=UTF-8"
}
```

Resource given in the request is actually matching, which I mentioned in API.
Any help is appreciated.

Resource Definition
[image]

Comment: Can you add your resource definitions as screenshot here?

Comment: please find the image here, http://prntscr.com/bdamuo

Comment: I can't reproduce your error locally.

Comment: Even I do not understand, because resource definition is correct and other methods work, only Put is not working.

Comment: Anyway, You have defined same URL with two HTTP method, which is other issue I found.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Now Put is working. But I need to have two more PUT with same URI. How can I add those?

Comment: I have added that as the asnwer. How do you expect to behave for having same URL for different HTTP method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having two PUT with same URL. You can't have two different HTTP resource with same URL.

Comment: I was confused. Yes we can not have two different HTTP resource with same URL. Actually I can perform all updates using one PUT request. Thanks for highlighting this.